# How to add/remove a Sub menuItem under the NSMenuItem

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsmenu, nsmenuitem

How to add/remove a `Sub MenuItem` under the `NSMenuItem` dynamically at runtime?

Comment: The `NSMenu` class has a bunch of methods to do that.

Comment: Am new to mac, am search related this and i didn't get a correct way, please help.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Do you mean add an item to a menu?

Comment: what exactly i want to do with my mac app is to show the recent windows under the Window Menu like the other default apps.

Comment: Yes i need to add a item to menu @trojanfoe

Comment: Well looking at the `NSMenu` class reference I can see some pretty obvious looking methods.

Comment: I have a menu called "Window" under the main Menu. I need to add the item to Window menu which named "Tutorial".

Comment: Why have you just edited your question to replace `NSMenu` with `NSMenuItem`?  That is incorrect (as it was originally) as you will be adding/removing items from an `NSMenu` object.

Comment: now got it what am trying to say ?

Comment: if u have a solution please post your answer. Thanks. @trojanfoe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution .

```
NSMenu  *mainMenu = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainMenu];
NSMenu  *appMenu = [[mainMenu itemAtIndex:5] submenu];

NSMenuItem *item=[[NSMenuItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Tutorial" action:@selector(actionTutorial:) keyEquivalent:@"T"];

[item setTarget:self];
[item setTag:0];


[appMenu addItem:item];
[appMenu removeItemAtIndex:2]; // which is the index of above added item.
```